# MySQL right outer join with multiple select statements is very slow

Tags: mysql, join, select, query-optimization, outer-join

I have 3 tables which look like this:

Resolution Table (table1)

```
+----+---------+-----+------------+--------+
| id | created | num | resolution | score  |
+----+---------+-----+------------+--------+
```

Author Table (table2)

```
+----+---------+--------+------+------+--------+
| id | created | author | file | tags | res_id |
+----+---------+--------+------+------+--------+
```

Status Table (table3)

```
+----+------+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+
| id | name | description | category | status | author_id |
+----+------+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+
```

I'm using 2 select statements to fetch records based on their's IDs like this from the same tables:

statement1 (resolution num = 1357)

```
select * 
from table1, table2, table3 
where table1.num=1357 
  and table1.id=table2.res_id
  and table2.id=table3.author_id;
```

statement2 (resolution num = 1358)

```
select * 
from table1, table2, table3 
where table1.num=1358 
  and table1.id=table2.res_id 
  and table2.id=table3.author_id;
```

**Note**: Each of the statements return 100,000+ records

I use right outer join to fetch records in statement2 that do not exist in statement1 results like this:

```
select * from (
  select * 
  from table1, table2, table3 
  where table1.num=1357 
    and table1.id=table2.res_id 
    and table2.id=table3.author_id
) as tab1
right outer join (
  select * 
  from table1, table2, table3 
  where table1.num=1358 
    and table1.id=table2.res_id 
    and table2.id=table3.author_id
) as tab2 on tab1.name=tab2.name
         and tab1.category=tab2.category
         and tab1.author=tab2.author
where tab1.name is NULL
  and tab1.category is NULL
  and tab1.author is NULL
```

This works well with small number of records but in my case with a combined 200,000 records it typically takes 11 mins to return the desired results.

How can i optimize the query to fetch results faster?

**PS:**

After applying indexes to table1.num, table2.res_id, table3.author_id

> show create table table1;

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `resolution` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `num` (`num`)
  KEY `num_index` (`num`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2552 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> show create table table2;

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `file` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `res_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `table2_res_id_48009073_fk_table1_id` (`res_id`),
  KEY `res_id_index` (`res_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `table2_res_id_48009073_fk_table1_id ` FOREIGN KEY (`res_id`) REFERENCES `table1` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=686972 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> show create table table3;

```
CREATE TABLE `table3` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `table3_ffe73c23` (`author_id`),
  KEY `author_id_index` (`author_id`)
  CONSTRAINT `table3_id_e47d088c_fk_table2_id` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `table2` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12042452 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> explain <"full select query">

```
+------+----------------+-----------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+------------------------------------+
| id     | select_type | table      | type        | possible_keys                                                                                | key                                                                    | key_len     | ref             | rows | Extra                                  |
+------+----------------+-----------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+------------------------------------+
|    1   | SIMPLE      | table1   | const   | PRIMARY,num,num_index                                                             | num                                                                  | 4               | const        | 1       | Using index                         |
|    1   | SIMPLE      | table2   | ref        | PRIMARY,table2_res_id_48009073_fk_table1_id,res_id_index.  | table2_res_id_48009073_fk_table1_id.           | 4               | const         | 7106 |                                            |
|    1.  | SIMPLE      | table3   | ref       | table3_ffe73c23,author_id_index                                                  | table3_ffe73c23                                                | 4               | t2.id           | 9       |                                            |
|    1   | SIMPLE      | table1   | const    | PRIMARY,num,num_index                                                           | num                                                                   | 4               | const         | 1       | Using where; Using index  |
|    1   | SIMPLE      | table2   | ref        | PRIMARY, table2_res_id_48009073_fk_table1_id,res_id_index  | table2_res_id_48009073_fk_table1_id.           | 4               | t1.id.          | 213   | Using where                       |
|    1   | SIMPLE      | table3   | ref        | table3_ffe73c23, author_id_index                                                 | table3_ffe73c23                                                | 4               | t2.id           | 9       | Using where; Not exists     |
+------+----------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+-------+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: What are the PKs? What indexes do all three tables have?

Comment: Try putting the results of the subqueries in temporary tables, so you can add indexes to them.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` statements for the three tables. The information that provides will provide a lot of help in answering your question.

Comment: @TheImpaler Primary keys are just the "id" columns for each table

Comment: @WillemRenzema i updated my question with SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename results

Comment: @VinayPotluri Thanks. I'm looking into your question now. Please note that the indexes RickJames suggested were already present, so you didn't need to add them again. I would drop those so they don't slow down your INSERTs to these tables.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: How long does it take to run the subquery for `tab1` by itself?

Comment: @RickJames mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.6-MariaDB, for osx10.14 (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: @RickJames it's pretty fast.  tab1 & tab2 each take approx ~ (0.114 sec)

Comment: @VinayPotluri - Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: @RickJames please check my question with the updated output of "explain" command

Answer (score 0):

```
where table1.num=1357 
  and table1.id=table2.res_id
  and table2.id=table3.author_id;
```

begs for these indexes:

```
table1:  INDEX(num)
table2:  INDEX(res_id)
table3:  INDEX(author_id)
```

Make those changes, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, then we can better look at the rest of the question.

How big is `description` usually?  If it is typically bigger than a few KB, then hauling it around (`table3.*`, `tab3.*`) is quite costly.  If you don't need the column in the result, then spell out `*` so as to exclude it.

If you *do* need `description` in the result, still do the above, but then add another `JOIN` back into `table3` to get it and any other columns that are not needed for the joins.

Comment: Note that `tab1` and `tab2` are derived tables, so you can't create indexes for those. (The fact that there are derived tables is likely the bulk of the performance problem, but I'll go into that in my own answer, if they provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements.)

Comment: @WillemRenzema - Oops.  I removed them.

Comment: @VinayPotluri - Looks like you already had those indexes.  Well, back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following re-written query:

```
SELECT
table1.*,
table2.*,
table3.*
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table2.res_id = table1.id
INNER JOIN table3
ON table3.author_id = table2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT
  table3.name,
  table3.category,
  table2.author
  FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2
  ON table2.res_id = table1.id
  INNER JOIN table3
  ON table3.author_id = table2.id
  WHERE table1.num = 1357
) tab1
ON tab1.name = table3.name
AND tab1.category = table3.category
AND tab1.author = table2.author
WHERE table1.num = 1358
AND tab1.name IS NULL
```

The query alone should probably show some improvements. If it doesn't improve much, try the following new indexes:

```
table2: INDEX(res_id, author)
table3: INDEX(author_id, category, name)
```

Then report back the results.

Note: When trying out the query, make sure to run it twice and discard the first result, so that the InnoDB buffer cache is populated.

Comment: I tried your solution with a couple of runs but the performance did not seem to improve.   

Without indexes - 1631 rows in set (53 min 11.668 sec)   -
   With indexes - 1631 rows in set (16 min 50.934 sec)  . 

In my case joins didn't feel any faster than where clause